# Tchart Rectangle Tool

Tags: teechart

I am evaluating Teechart 4.1.2012.2287 and I have a problem with the rectangle tool.
My project is written in VS2010, using VB.Net and framework 4.0.

If you place a rectangle tool, and set the position units to percent (I need to do this so that the rectangle stays in roughly the same position when I resize the chart) the grab hand does not show when the mouse pointer is over the rectangle. It does actually incorrectly show at the corresponding pixel location rather than the percentage location.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to reproduce the issue, with the code snippet below, and added it (TF02016130) to the defect list to be investigated.

```
  tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
  tChart1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

  tChart1.Series.Add(new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Points()).FillSampleValues();

  Steema.TeeChart.Tools.RectangleTool rectangle1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Tools.RectangleTool(tChart1.Chart);

  rectangle1.Text = "My rectangle tool";
  rectangle1.AutoSize = true;
  rectangle1.PositionUnits = Steema.TeeChart.PositionUnits.Percent;
  rectangle1.Shape.CustomPosition = true;
  rectangle1.Shape.Left = 50;
  rectangle1.Shape.Top = 50;
  rectangle1.AllowDrag = true;
  rectangle1.AllowResize = true;
  rectangle1.AllowEdit = true;
```

In the meantime, a workaround is using the *AfterDraw* event and pixel positioning as shown here:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  InitializeChart();
}

private Steema.TeeChart.Tools.RectangleTool rectangle1;

private void InitializeChart()
{
  tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
  tChart1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

  tChart1.Series.Add(new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Points()).FillSampleValues();

  rectangle1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Tools.RectangleTool(tChart1.Chart);

  tChart1.AfterDraw += new Steema.TeeChart.PaintChartEventHandler(tChart1_AfterDraw);

  rectangle1.Text = "My rectangle tool";
  rectangle1.AutoSize = true;
  rectangle1.PositionUnits = Steema.TeeChart.PositionUnits.Pixels;
  rectangle1.AllowDrag = true;
  rectangle1.AllowResize = true;
  rectangle1.AllowEdit = true;

  tChart1.Draw();
}

void tChart1_AfterDraw(object sender, Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.Graphics3D g)
{
  rectangle1.Shape.CustomPosition = true;
  rectangle1.Shape.Left = tChart1.Width / 2;
  rectangle1.Shape.Top = tChart1.Height / 2;
}
```

Comment: Investigating it a little bit further, I found these are actually 2 different issues, so I've split it in two (TF02016131 and TF02016132). TF02016131 is that the clicked function doesn't cosider when PositionUnits=Percent. I've just fixed it, so the next maintenance release should show the dragging/resizing mouse cursor style at the correct position. And TF02016132 is regarding the internal transformations between percent and pixels to make the drag&resize work. I've partially corrected it.

Comment: When is the next maintenance release due to be released?

Comment: @Ross No date has been established yet. We try to have a version out every two months approximately. Given that the current version was published one month ago we'd like to have the next maintenance release ready in about another month. Please stay tuned to Steema Software communication channels.